# Django paginator to include all elements of all previous pages

Tags: django, paginator

I read the [docs on Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/pagination/) with Django and can't find a solution to my problem there. I want to paginate a queryset (5 elements per page) so that my `object_list` contains **all elements of all previous pages** up to the ones of the requested page.

This is what normally happens when I call for for the objects of page 2:

```
>>> p = Paginator(queryset, 5)  # 5 elements per page
>>> page2 = p.page(2)
>>> page2.object_list
['6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

What I want to get is this:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that's how the Pagination object is designed to work. I suspect it's going to be easier to implement something yourself. Whatever you do, try something, then post some code explaining how you got on, and what errors you hit.

Answer (score 1):

enter code hereIt's normal, because, this is what the object Paginator do

```
page1 = p.page(1)
page1.object_list
```

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (5 items per page, from item(1) to item(5), this is the first page)

```
page2 = p.page(2)
page2.object_list
```

['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'](5 items per page, from item(6) to item(10),this is the second page)

**The definition of object Paginator:
Give Paginator a list of objects, plus the number of items you’d like to have on each page,**